# Measuring Sharepoint 2010 availability programmatically

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, monitoring

I would like to measure the following with regards to system availability and performance in Sharepoint 2010:

- Uptime & Downtime
- Average Page load time
- Average Upload time
- CPU usage

I have seen the answers to the question posted [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73221/how-to-measure-sharepoint-availability) but am I able to measure system availability and performance with the use of custom code (i.e. using Pascal, C#, etc)? Or third-party software is the only way to do it?

Comment: check this from scoial forum of technet..http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1e49a81c-cfe3-422b-a50d-2f3a513667d0/monitoring-moss-2007-programmatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy specially answer from Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uptime & Downtime- Server Monitoring

Average Page load time - SP Developer Dashboard

Average Upload time - SP Developer Dashboard

CPU usage - Server Monitoring

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but how do I go to "Server Monitoring"?